# How to pay with paypal and then save parameters from my form?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, express-checkout

I have a working website (HTML, bootstrap)

It has a form where I collect various data regarding the user (e.g. email, dates). Upon clicking "Finish" button, the form sends all data to server (which I have developed on python). The server registers the user by saving all the data collected from the form.

I would like to add a PayPal payment system so that the user will pay for registration and then my server-side script will be initiated and all the data that was in the form will be saved. i.e. the same as now, I just want the user to pay and then save the data.

As far members over here adviced, I have to do "Express Checkout Payment Method" (**Am I right?**). But the explanations I saw in the web were not clear and I cant figure out how to do it.

**How can it be done?**

Comment: I have a Express Checkout Setup made in my project. Would you mind If I share it with you? But you have to give me some time, because its a big script and explanation....

Comment: @Saswat, I would be glad to! Thanks. Will it be clear from your code how to do it?

Comment: Yes, @Yura. However, my codes are based on Codeigniter framework(php), but if you have concepts about function calling and basic idea about how the OOP works, you won't have any problem to get it done as you want

Comment: I will be constantly editing my answer, so be patient while I am updating...

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation of how Express Checkout works:

Express Checkout Method is a paypal transaction method which is basically split into 3 phases, namely:

1. **SetExpressCheckout**: To use Express Checkout, you would call the SetExpressCheckout API. In the API call, you specify the details of
   the products, amounts, and the RETURNURL.
2. **GetExpressCheckout**: Once the buyer has agreed to your purchase, he is redirected back to the URL you specified in the RETURNURL. You
   should now show the order confirmation, and call the
   GetExpressCheckoutDetails API**. When calling
   GetExpressCheckoutDetails, supply the token. In the
   GetExpressCheckoutDetails API response you'll find a PayerID.
3. **DoExpressCheckout**: Now you're ready to call DoExpressCheckoutPayment, and charge the buyer. Remember to include both the token and the payerID when calling DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

First goes the *cancel function*. If a payment is cancelled, then this method will be called.

```
function payment_failure()
{
    echo "payment cancelled by the user";
}
```

---

Now comes the *payment successful* method:

```
function payment_success()
{
    // Obtain the token from PayPal.
    if(!array_key_exists('token', $_REQUEST)) 
         exit('Token is not received.');

    // Set request-specific fields.
    $token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['token']));

    // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
    $nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token";

    // Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
    $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $nvpStr);

    if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
      {
          $payerID = urlencode($httpParsedResponseAr["PAYERID"]);
          $paymentType = urlencode('Sale');             // or 'Sale' or 'Order'
          $paymentAmount = urlencode($_SESSION['total_amount']);
          $currencyID = urlencode($_SESSION['cur']);    // or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')


                $nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token&PAYERID=$payerID&PAYMENTACTION=$paymentType&AMT=$paymentAmount&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";
                $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $nvpStr);
                if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
                { 

                    $transaction_secret=md5(uniqid());

                    unset($_SESSION['fname']);
                    unset($_SESSION['lname']);
                    unset($_SESSION['email']);
                    unset($_SESSION['password']);
                    // save the data in the database along with a secret key to uniquely identify the user later(if needed).
                }
                else  
                {
                        exit('DoExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
                    //echo "Payment failed for unknown reason";
                }
          } 
      } 
  else  
      {
        //exit('GetExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
        echo "Payment failed for unknown reason";
      }
}
```

---

The first two are the *success method* and the *cancel methods*. 
Now comes the function which accepts the data from the submit form, and calls the `ExpressCheckout` methods by passing the parameter to the `ExpressCheckout` method...

```
function paypal_order()
{
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $_POST['fname']; // fetching the data submitted from the form
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $_SESSION['lname']);
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_SESSION['email']);
        $_SESSION['password'] = $_SESSION['password'];

        if($_SESSION['cur']=='USD')
            $currencyID = urlencode('USD');
        else if($_SESSION['cur']=='INR')
        {
            $_SESSION['cur'] = 'USD';
            $currencyID = urlencode('USD');
        }
        else if($_SESSION['cur']=='EUR')
            $currencyID = urlencode('EUR');
        else if($_SESSION['cur']=='GBP')
            $currencyID = urlencode('GBP');   

        $paymentType = urlencode('Order'); 

        $returnURL = (base_url()."paypal-payment-success"); // this call the payment_success() method using the router technique;
        $cancelURL = (base_url()."paypal-payment-failure");  // this call the payment_failure() method using the router technique;
        $nvpStr="&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=$returnURL
&CANCELURL=$cancelURL"; 

        $i=0;
        $str = "
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME$i=User-Registration
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER$i=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT$i=20
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC$i=User-Registration";  
      $nvpStr=$nvpStr.$str;

    $nvpStr=$nvpStr."&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=20&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID";

    $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);

    if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]))
    {
        $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);
        $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
        if("sandbox" === $environment) 
                {
            $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
            }
        header("Location: $payPalURL");
        exit;
    } 
    else  
    {
        exit('SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
    }
}
```

---

And ultimately, the following is the **httppost** method which is called by the pasing params like, **SetExpressCheckout**, **GetExpressCheckout** and **DoExpressCheckout**.

The following function is called thrice in a scuccessful Express Checkout Transaction:

```
 private function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) 
 {

      // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.

      $environment = "sandbox"; //or "live" for original live transaction;
      $API_UserName = "expresscheckout API username goes here";
      $API_Password = "expresscheckout API password goes here";
      $API_Signature = "expresscheckout API signature goes here";

      //$API_UserName = urlencode('saswat_paypay_business_api1.gmail.com');
      //$API_Password = urlencode('1365495686');
      //$API_Signature = urlencode('AfOa1sjCuxeiTRYj4tqlG6nUGUmhAvv0pzdavzgFM3272hn8CqS5OY0A');

      $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
      if("sandbox" === $environment) 
      {
           $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
      }
      $version = urlencode('65.0');

     // Set the curl parameters.
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

     // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

     // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
      $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

     // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

     // Get response from the server.
     $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

     if(!$httpResponse) 
     {
         exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
     }

     // Extract the response details.
     $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

     $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
     foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) 
     {
         $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
         if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) 
         {
             $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
         }
     }

     if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) 
     {
          exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
     }

     return $httpParsedResponseAr;
 }
```

Your form submission should make the data flow to, or redirect to the function **paypal_order()** which is responsible for calling all the other functions.

Comment: Thanks! How do I call these functions? When and What should I do in the HTML?

Comment: @Yura, my answer is complete..... You can review it. Please feel free to ask if you face any confusion.